# Windows 10 Installation Error - Memory Management

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I created a bootable USB using windows 10 tool. All worked fine but at the end of the installation I am getting MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error. I installed 3 times and downloaded ISO in my USB twice but it didn't help me. I Googled but couldn't found solution.

My laptop specs are: Intel core i5, 6 GM RAM, 512 GB SSD and Windows 7 Ultimate OS.

Here is the error screen

[image]

P.s. I have no issue with Windows 7 and I ran memory diagnostic all seems good.

Comment: So did you search online later? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/blue-screen-with-memory-management-error/0ef94515-c9ee-4a3d-8a6a-936a6dc09e8d When you get back into Windows 7, open a Command Prompt and enter `sfc/ scannow`.

Comment: Yes. I did but nothing found related to windows 10. Tried sfc all good.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then. It wouldn't install on my laptop either for unknown reasons. My error code was `BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG` or something but that laptop is old anyways.

Comment: run the memory diagnostics in windows 7, open a run box (Win key +R) and type in "mdsched.exe" without quotes, a window opens, select restart. See if you get any test errors.

Comment: in Win7, run CPU-Z and check that the RAM timings in the memory tab match to the data from the SPD tab: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html